# Can you audit user exports from Snowflake's UI?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

Snowflake makes it easy to audit queries users make against the data warehouse by providing a set of `QUERY_HISTORY` views. Is there an analogous table that keeps track of data export actions, too?

The `ROWS_UNLOADED` column and its equivalents seem to point in the direction of the query itself writing to an external system, but not a UI initiated data download.

Answer (score 0):

No such table exists, plus once the data has reached the client it is effectively exported anyway, right?  The user could copy/paste it, transcribe it, screenshot it, access it via Javascript, or any multiple of "exports" besides the "Export" button.